# findFirst throws java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I have this code below.
The `findfirst` call is throwing `NullPointerException` even though I have an `orElseGet` call chained

```
int numberOfRetry = 5;
String req = "abc";
String res =
    Stream.iterate(0, n -> n + 1).map(i -> {
        try {
            return req.substring(numberOfRetry - i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log exception
        }
        return null;
    })
    .limit(1)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseGet(() -> "Exception");
```

However, it works fine if I put a filter call as shown below:

```
int numberOfRetry = 5;
String req = "abc";
String res =
    Stream.iterate(0, n -> n + 1).map(i -> {
        try {
            return req.substring(numberOfRetry - i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log exception
        }
        return null;
    })
    .limit(1)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseGet(() -> "Exception");
```

I guess we cannot explicitly return `null` in some situations, and it is not quite clear what those situations are at first glance. In the first case it returns a `stream` with the `null` element in it which throws `NullPointerException`, in the second case it returns an empty stream which works fine.

Comment: since you've updated the question, does *handle exception* means returning some value as well?

Comment: @nullpointer I just log the exception in the `catch` block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is explicitly returning `null`

```
return null
```

which thereafter throws NPE, according to the spec of  [`Optional.findFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst()) which reads:

> ```
> @throws NullPointerException if the element selected is null
> Optional<T> findFirst();
> ```

Also, to clarify the code control couldn't even reach the `orElseGet` part which anyway assumingly works over an `Optional` (either empty or with some value).

---

Few suggestions :

- Don't ignore exceptions, especially when you've caught the most generic out of them all.
- Avoid returning `null` explicitly from within an iteration, it seems contradictory to why you'd iterate then.
- Safer side *in your code currently*, you can filter-in only nonNull objects using `filter` as

  ```
  Stream.iterate(0, n -> n + 1).map(i -> {
         try {
             return req.substring(numberOfRetry - i);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             err.add(e);
         }
         return null;
  })
  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
  .limit(1)
  .findFirst()
  .orElse("Exception");
  ```

Answer (score 3):

From the [javadoc for `findFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--):

> Throws:
>       NullPointerException - if the element selected is null

`Optional` cannot differentiate between "present but null" and "not present"

Answer (score 3):

What do you think happens when you do:

```
System.out.println(req.substring(numberOfRetry - i));
```

where `i` for the first time is `zero`? An out of bounds exception will be thrown - which you catch and return `null`; so you have a `Stream.of(null)` which you call `findFirst` on - which is documented to throw that `NullPointerException` is case the element is null.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you return `null` in your map function.
Try to add `.filter(s -> s != null)` after `map` operation.